# vueform/multiselect not working as a single file component

Tags: vue.js, vue-multiselect

I'm getting really strange errors while trying to implement vueform/multiselect. Most of the examples that I have found do not use single-file components and that's the approach I want to take. I'm trying to import the MultiSelect component into another component called 'AgentDetails'. I'm using VUE-CLI and VUE 3.

**CustomSelect.vue**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <Multiselect v-model="value" :options="options" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Multiselect from "@vueform/multiselect";

export default {
  components: {
    Multiselect
  },
  data() {
    return {
      value: "Batman",
      options: ["Batman", "Robin", "Joker"]
    };
  }
};
</script>

<style src="@vueform/multiselect/themes/default.css"></style>
```

**AgentDetails.vue (here's where I want to insert the CustomSelect component)**

```
    <template>
    <CustomSelect />
    </template>
    <script>
    import { mapState, mapActions } from "vuex";
    import CustomSelect from "@/components/CustomSelect.vue";
    export default {
      components: {
        CustomSelect
      }
    };
    </script>
```

I keep getting these errors:

> ````
> execution of setup function    at <Multiselect modelValue=null
> onUpdate:modelValue=fn options= (3) ["Batman", "Robin", "Joker"] >   
> at <CustomSelect>    at <AgentDetails>    at <AgentDetails
> agentEmail="alexandra.blanco@rubiko.tech"
> onVnodeUnmounted=fn<onVnodeUnmounted> ref=Ref< null > >    at
> <RouterView>    at <App> warn @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:38
> logError @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:211 handleError @
> runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:203 callWithErrorHandling @
> runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:157 setupStatefulComponent @
> runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:6224 setupComponent @
> runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:6185 mountComponent @
> runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:3960 processComponent @
> runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:3936 patch @
> runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:3547 mountChildren @
> runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:3736 mountElement @
> runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:3659 processElement @
> runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:3631 patch @
> runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:3544 componentEffect @
> runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:4053 reactiveEffect @
> reactivity.esm-bundler.js?a1e9:42 effect @
> reactivity.esm-bundler.js?a1e9:17 setupRenderEffect @
> runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:4018 mountComponent @
> runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:3976 processComponent @
> runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:3936 patch @
> runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:3547 mountChildren @
> runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:3736 mountElement @
> runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:3659 processElement @
> runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:3631 patch @
> runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:3544 mountChildren @
> runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:3736 mountElement @
> runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:3659 processElement @
> runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:3631 patch @
> runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:3544 mountChildren @
> runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:3736 mountElement @
> runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:3659 processElement @
> runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:3631 patch @
> runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:3544 mountChildren @
> runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:3736 mountElement @
> runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:3659 processElement @
> runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:3631 patch @
> runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:3544 mountChildren @
> runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:3736 mountElement @
> runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:3659 processElement @
> runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:3631 patch @
> runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:3544 mountChildren @
> runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:3736 mountElement @
> runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:3659 processElement @
> runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:3631 patch @
> runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:3544 componentEffect @
> runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:4053 reactiveEffect @
> reactivity.esm-bundler.js?a1e9:42 effect @
> reactivity.esm-bundler.js?a1e9:17 setupRenderEffect @
> runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:4018 mountComponent @
> runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:3976 processComponent @
> runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:3936 patch @
> runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:3547 mountChildren @
> runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:3736 mountElement @
> runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:3659 processElement @
> runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:3631 patch @
> runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:3544 componentEffect @
> runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:4053 reactiveEffect @
> reactivity.esm-bundler.js?a1e9:42 effect @
> reactivity.esm-bundler.js?a1e9:17 setupRenderEffect @
> runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:4018 mountComponent @
> runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:3976 processComponent @
> runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:3936 patch @
> runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:3547 componentEffect @
> runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:4117 reactiveEffect @
> reactivity.esm-bundler.js?a1e9:42 callWithErrorHandling @
> runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:154 flushJobs @
> runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:364 Promise.then (async) queueFlush @
> runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:264 queueJob @
> runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:258 run @
> reactivity.esm-bundler.js?a1e9:183 trigger @
> reactivity.esm-bundler.js?a1e9:189 set value @
> reactivity.esm-bundler.js?a1e9:721 finalizeNavigation @
> vue-router.esm-bundler.js?6c02:2585 eval @
> vue-router.esm-bundler.js?6c02:2458 Promise.then (async)
> pushWithRedirect @ vue-router.esm-bundler.js?6c02:2429 push @
> vue-router.esm-bundler.js?6c02:2369 navigate @
> vue-router.esm-bundler.js?6c02:1997 callWithErrorHandling @
> runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:154 callWithAsyncErrorHandling @
> runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:163 invoker @
> runtime-dom.esm-bundler.js?830f:292 Show 36 more frames
> runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:38 [Vue warn]: Unhandled error during
> execution of scheduler flush. This is likely a Vue internals bug.
> Please open an issue at
> https://new-issue.vuejs.org/?repo=vuejs/vue-next    at <Multiselect
> modelValue=null onUpdate:modelValue=fn options= (3) ["Batman",
> "Robin", "Joker"] >    at <CustomSelect>    at <AgentDetails>    at
> <AgentDetails agentEmail="alexandra.blanco@rubiko.tech"
> onVnodeUnmounted=fn<onVnodeUnmounted> ref=Ref< null > >    at
> <RouterView>    at <App> warn @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:38
> logError @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:211 handleError @
> runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:203 callWithErrorHandling @
> runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:157 flushJobs @
> runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:364 Promise.then (async) queueFlush @
> runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:264 queueJob @
> runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:258 run @
> reactivity.esm-bundler.js?a1e9:183 trigger @
> reactivity.esm-bundler.js?a1e9:189 set value @
> reactivity.esm-bundler.js?a1e9:721 finalizeNavigation @
> vue-router.esm-bundler.js?6c02:2585 eval @
> vue-router.esm-bundler.js?6c02:2458 Promise.then (async)
> pushWithRedirect @ vue-router.esm-bundler.js?6c02:2429 push @
> vue-router.esm-bundler.js?6c02:2369 navigate @
> vue-router.esm-bundler.js?6c02:1997 callWithErrorHandling @
> runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:154 callWithAsyncErrorHandling @
> runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:163 invoker @
> runtime-dom.esm-bundler.js?830f:292 multiselect.js?a306:1 Uncaught (in
> promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined
>     at re (multiselect.js?a306:1)
>     at q (multiselect.js?a306:1)
>     at setup (multiselect.js?a306:1)
>     at callWithErrorHandling (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:154)
>     at setupStatefulComponent (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:6224)
>     at setupComponent (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:6185)
>     at mountComponent (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:3960)
>     at processComponent (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:3936)
>     at patch (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:3547)
>     at mountChildren (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:3736)```
> ````

Comment: Vue multiselect is not Vue 3 ready yet. Use [this](https://github.com/shentao/vue-multiselect/issues/1369) as an interim solution.

Comment: Thanks, @tao I tried with that one too and I'm getting the same error will update my question with the new implementation tho, please take a look.

Comment: many thanks for correcting my layout mistakes here @mousetail

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok figure out what was happening, in order for the multi-select to work you need to have a particular object structure on the component data, if not Vue won't instantiate the component and you will get a lot of weird errors, here's an example:

```
  options: {
    value: [],
    options: [
      { value: "batman", label: "Batman" },
      { value: "robin", label: "Robin" },
      { value: "joker", label: "Joker" }
    ]
  }
```

Comment: After so much frustration this helped me. Thanks for this!